# Remove Repeated Text

Tags: regex

Can someone modify this Regex to remove words as in the example:

This does not work with extra in it below:    `(<.+?\/>)(?=\1)`

```
<text><text>extra<words><text><words><something>
```

Should turn into:

```
<text>extra<words><something>
```

Thanks

Comment: What's your logic? Do you want to drop all but the first occurrence of each `<tag>`? And, very important, which language do you want to use this pattern in?

Comment: I would use the regex to match a pattern (the purpose of regex), then add it to an array if the array does not already contain the match.  Then I would just implode the array for the output.  There are probably other ways, but I think with any method, regex is a component of the solution, not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've come up with using lookbehinds and back references:

```
(<[^>]+>)(?<=\1.*\1)
```

This will match any instance of `<tag>` which is preceded by at least one other instance of the same `<tag>`.

For example, to use this in C#:

```
var input = "<text><text>extra<words><text><words><something>";
var output Regex.Replace(input, @"(<[^>]+>)(?<=\1.*\1)", "");
Console.WriteLine(output); // <text>extra<words><something>
```

However, this will not work in many flavors of regex. JavaScript, for example, does not support lookbehinds.