# Regex for getting the first occurring matching pair

Tags: regex

Given that you can reference a capture group in a regex pattern, is it possible to use said capture group in a `lookbehind`?

if you have the string

```
"monkeys eat bananas, bananas are terrified of monkeys"
```

bananas is the first matched pair, while monkeys is the first word that has a match.  I can get monkeys without any issue

```
(\w+).*\1 # returns monkeys
```

But if I want to get the word which matches first I would need to be able to do something like this

```
(?<=\1)(\w+)
```

However, this fails, and I would guess for the simple reason that when the `lookbehind` is evaluated, `\1` means nothing.  Is there some more regex magic that I have not come across yet, that would allow me to match something like this?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting by matching first?

Comment: I'm trying to get the first matching pair, so in my example bananas gets repeated before monkeys, so bananas is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many regular expression engines require backreferences to appear *after* the group which they reference (see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344034/do-backreferences-need-to-come-after-the-group-they-reference) about this behavior in .NET)

Try using a lookahead instead:

```
(\w+)(?=.*\1)
```

Comment: Isn't this the equivalent of `(\w+).*\1`? i.e. `(\w+)` matches monkeys, and then the `lookahead` see that monkeys is repeated?

Comment: @miah Not precisely. In `(\w).*\1` the whole match consists of the entire string between both instances (with only the first instance captured in a group). Using the lookahead, the whole match consists of just the first instance. That means that given your above sample, this pattern would match both `monkeys` and `bananas` (yours would match only `monkeys`).